# How do I find all possible permutations of a string with only single swap?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, permutation

The complexity should be O(n) where n is length of string.
Ex: For 'abc', answer is 'bac', 'cba', 'acb'.
'bca' and 'cab' should not be in the list as two swaps are required to convert it to 'abc'.

I have made a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm but it is very slow.

```
def f(s):
    temp=list(s)
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s)):
            temp=list(s)
            temp[i],temp[j]=temp[j],temp[i]
            l.append("".join(str(i) for i in temp))
    print set(l)
```

Comment: There can't be any O(n) solution since there are more than O(n) answers.

Comment: You can swap any element with any other, so there are n(n-1)/2 solutions and your O(n²) algorithm is optimal. But is it really wise to convert to list and join all the time ?

Answer (score 3):

The number of possible outcomes for a string (with distinct characters) of length `n` is `nC2 = n * (n-1) / 2`, since we can choose two letters at any two indices and swap them.

Hence, if you plan to print all of the outcomes, the complexity will be `O(n^2)` and a `O(n)` solution is not possible.

For duplicate characters, the reasoning becomes more complex. Suppose there is exactly one duplicate character repeated `k` times. Then there are `n-k` swaps that will be identical. So if there is exactly one character repeated, and it is repeated `k` times, the number of possibilities is `nC2 - (n-k)`. This can be extended to more repeated characters using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: what if we have duplicate characters?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations` to find all possible combination of two char index, then swapped it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import itertools


def f(s):
    result = []
    # This will produce: [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]
    for idx1, idx2 in itertools.combinations(range(len(s)), 2):
        swapped_s = list(s)
        swapped_s[idx1], swapped_s[idx2] = swapped_s[idx2], swapped_s[idx1]
        result.append(''.join(swapped_s))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print f('abc')
```

The above code will give you the correct result:

```
['bac', 'cba', 'acb']
```

Hope it helps!